# What is wrong with my constraints?

Tags: autolayout, uikit, constraints

I am simply trying to create a view with a contained view that is 50% as tall and high.  In the following code, I set constraints to achieve that when I add the view to the super-view.  I set translatesAutoResizingMaskToConstraints to false, add the constraints via anchors. I also tried to call setNeedsUpdateConstraints, and add the same constraints in updateConstraints.

But in the following Playground code, I don't see the constrained subview `testView`.  I expect to see an blue view half the size of the orange view, but all i see is orange.

I'm not sure what I am missing here.

```
   //: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport


    class LView: UIView {

        var testView = UILabel()

        override init(frame: CGRect) {
            super.init(frame: frame)

            self.backgroundColor = .orange

            setup()
        }

        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }

        private func setup() {

            addSubview(testView)
            testView.backgroundColor = .blue

            testView.text = "....."
            //testView.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()

            testView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

            testView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5).isActive = true
            testView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.5).isActive = true
            testView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor).isActive = true
            testView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true


        }


    }

    let testView = LView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
    PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = testView
```

Comment: It took me a few tries for the liveView to even show up, but when it did the blue view is there.  I believe your constraints are fine, but Playground is being flaky.  Try adding `testView.layoutIfNeeded()` after `let testView...`.